# In what cases should I use a comma after "please"?

Tags: punctuation, commas, politeness, sentence-ends

As far as I can see from different texts, there seems to be no strict rule about putting comma after "Please" when it is used as an introduction to a request. Am I right?

In what cases using comma after "please" would be correct or even compulsory? What if "please" is put in the end of such sentence?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It is simply a matter of emphasis, which is why you can see it written both ways. For instance, if you had a visitor at your house, who was going to leave the house after you had left it, you might say:

> Please don't forget to lock the door when you leave.

However, if this particular person had a habit of leaving the door unlocked, you would want to emphasize the "please", and could do it like so:

> Please, don't forget to lock the door when you leave.

Which, when said out loud, has a louder "please" than the first example.

Basically, it emphasizes the importance of the request.

Also, if the "please" is at the end of a sentence, there must always be a comma, e.g.:

> Don't forget to lock the door, please.

Comment: It's a very good answer! But does anyone here have any link to some authoritative resource that would support this answer?

Comment: @brilliant: This is one of the cases where resources probably aren't necessary.

Comment: @simchona - Why? There should be some academic proof to this answer, otherwise how can I be sure that it's true?

Comment: @brilliant There are some things that are a matter of *style* and personal taste.

Comment: Is it allowed to put `please` in the middle of the sentence? And if yes, are those "rules" applied also?

Comment: @brilliant 11 years later and there's still no proof to this answer. :(

Comment: @Diecie - Some things take time.       :)

Answer (score 12):

There is no strict rule, you are right.  But inserting or omitting the comma after a leading "Please" can change the meaning of your sentence.

The comma is required in some cases.

A comma is almost always required before "please" at the end of the sentence.

Whether to use a comma or not depends on what you mean to say.  "Please" can be a verb, an adverb or an interjection.  When used to implore or request, it is an adverb modifying the verb of the requested action.  The usage of punctuation (such as a comma) can change the meaning of the word by changing its part of speech.

> "Please! Eat your broccoli."

In this case, "please" is clearly an **interjection** because it is set off by an exclamation mark.

> "Please, eat your broccoli."

Here "please" is also used as an **interjection** but with a milder emphasis.

> "Please eat your broccoli."

In this form, "please" is an **adverb** modifying the verb "eat".

**Rule of thumb:**
When an adverb is separated from the verb it modifies by phrases or other adverbs, it usually should be offset by a comma. When the adverb is adjacent to the verb it modifies, it should not have a comma.

> "Please eat your broccoli."

The **adverb** "please" modifies the verb "eat" and is adjacent to it, so a comma is not required.  But a comma may be added if the word "please" has some special emphasis in this context or is a transitional word from another sentence.

> "Eat your broccoli. Please eat your broccoli."
>
> "Eat your broccoli. Please, eat your broccoli."

In the first couplet, "please" is a simple **adverb**, as before.  In the second couplet, "please" is an **adverb** with special emphasis related to its context.  That emphasis is conveyed by the comma.  This is similar to the transitional usage I'll discuss next.

> "Why do I have to beg? Please, eat your broccoli."

"Please" is the "begging" referred to in the previous sentence, so a comma may be used to convey its usage as a **transitional adverb** between the two sentences.  But there is no hard and fast rule on this.

> "Please, for the last time, eat your broccoli."

The **adverb** "please" modifies "eat", but the two words are separated by a clause which is offset by commas.

> "Please, can you just eat your broccoli?"

The **adverb** "please" modifies "eat"; it does not modify "can".  Since it is separated from its verb, there is a comma.  Do not be fooled by the verb "can" which is unrelated to "Please".  A comma is required here.

> "Eat your broccoli, please."

Here the **adverb** follows at the end of the sentence and is not adjacent to the verb.  A comma is required for clarity.

> "Please, quickly eat your broccoli."

Multiple **adverbs** ("please" and "quickly") are both modifying the verb "eat", so the comma is needed to indicate that these are **sequential modifiers**.  On the other hand, this could be interpreted as an **interjection** similar to "Please! Quickly eat your broccoli."  Interpretation here depends on the context and the reader.

> "Please quickly eat your broccoli."

Removing the comma from the previous sentence changes its meaning (and removes ambiguity).  Now the word "please" is definitely an **adverb**, not an interjection. However, it is now modifying the adverb "quickly" rather than the verb "eat". The lack of a comma indicates the adverbs are not sequential modifiers, so we are left to interpret them this way.

Comment: I think your answer might benefit from some paring down.

Comment: This is a fully explained answer, I would buy this answer if I were the OP.