# "Please" and comma

Tags: punctuation, commas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In what cases should I use a comma after “please”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/389/in-what-cases-should-i-use-a-comma-after-please)

Do I have to use comma after "please" in the beginning of the sentence?
E.g. 
"Please, specify the reason."
or
"Please specify the reason."

Comment: I'd say separate *please* with commas because it is an interjection if it is at the end of a sentence.

Comment: But Wikipedia's article about interjection says different :)
http://screencast.com/t/4nGop9Y3VP